# Channel Global Admin Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have heard of cases where Microsoft teams channels have different permission roles.
Roles like

- Team Owner
- App Admin or Global Admin.

Am currently building a feature in Microsoft teams bot, I want to utilize channel permission levels to differentiate the roles of a bot admin, team owner and just a regular team member.

Please who has any idea how I can introduce these different permissions, that's if they are not there on default. Also if they exist how can I access them?

We want to check the user permissions from the task module in the Microsoft teams bot, How possible is this and how can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT  I just updated the question. What am trying to do is check the user permissions from the task module in the Microsoft teams bot, How possible is this and how can it be done?

Comment: Could you please share which user permissions you want to check from the task module?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, The permission i am using currently is TeamMember.Read.All, of which only gives me access to team administration permissions. Are there no better ways of getting global bot admin permissions?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue. What exactly are you trying to do. Share document which you are referring?

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels of permissions that must be taken care before giving permissions.

1. You can manage the app permission policies in Teams level

Check with the link mentioned: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies)

2. Microsoft Teams App permissions and considerations
   a. Bot Level
   b. Messaging extensions
   c. Tabs
   d. Connectors

Check the link mentioned: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/app-permissions)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers (they're not valid answers, and require someone to go offsite to learn more). The question itself is off-topic, as a general information-seeking question, without any programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main roles in Teams:

**Team owner** - The person who creates the team. Team owners can make any member of their team a co-owner when they invite them to the team or at any point after they've joined the team. Having multiple team owners lets you share the responsibilities of managing settings and membership, including invitations.

**Team members** - The people who the owners invite to join their team.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-channels-overview#membership-roles-and-settings

You can get the roles in conversationMember resource type.
You can go through below link for more details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conversationmember?view=graph-rest-1.0